# How to pull specific columns from Gmail CSV attachment to Google Spreadsheet using app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using an automated script which helps me pull a Gmail CSV attachment into a spreadsheet, but I want to parse only specific columns rather than the entire CSV file. Would be a great help if you can help here.

Here is the script:

```js
function getattach(){

    var threads = GmailApp.search('Daily Hunting file has:attachment newer_than:1d');

    var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
    var attach = messages[0].getAttachments();
    var timestamp = messages[0].getDate();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < attach.length; ++i) {
    
      var data = attach[i].copyBlob();
      var name = data.getName();
      
      var result = name.indexOf('report.csv');
      if (name.indexOf('report.csv')>-1) {
          var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(data.getDataAsString());
      } //end if
    
    } //end for
       
    return csvData;

}

function updateSheet(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ImportSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Import');
    
    var ImportData = getattach();

    //Write results to the Sheet
    var lastRow = ImportSheet.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow < 1) lastRow = 1;
    ImportSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow, ImportData[0].length).clearContent();
    ImportSheet.getRange(1,1,ImportData.length, ImportData[10].length).setValues(ImportData);
   
 }
```

Comment: What's the issue? Please include any errors you're receiving, what the current behavior of the code you provided is, and what your expected behavior is.

Comment: It's probably easier just to load the csv onto a spreadsheet an then just get the range of the column that you want witn something like `vs = sh.getRange(row,col,sh.getLastRow() - row + 1).getValues().flat();` now you have the values in vs as a 1D Array

Comment: The above script works fine for me with no errors during runtime but above script is returning me each column and row data from the CSV attachment and i want to limit columns not rows as per my need by changing some parameters into the above script. For instance in gmail CSV file, the data length is having 5 columns instead of pulling 5 columns from the above script i want to pull only 2 columns to the source sheet. Let me know if this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting a column from a csv file

```
function getColumnFromCSV(id="file id",col=9) {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
  const a = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  let o = a.map(r => r[col - 1]).flat()
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
}

Execution log
1:19:20 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:19:21 PM  Info    ["COL9","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28"]
1:19:22 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

File:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9,COL10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26
18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27
19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29
```